# How to redirect to same page from spring security AccessDeniedHandler

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have created `CustomAccessDeneiedHandler` class in a Spring MVC application which implements `AccessDeniedHandler` interface as like below.

```
    public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
     
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException exc) throws IOException, ServletException {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/accessDenied");
        }
   }
```

This will make the call to controller GET method with `"/accessDenied"` URI and which internally returns a JSP view specific to access denied error.

But, Instead of redirecting to separate view, I want to display an alert message on the same page saying something like "You don't have permission to perform this task".

Is there any workaround to do so that we can send the response back to the origin of the request page and display an error message on that page?
I tried many different approaches but nothing seems to work for me as every solution I tried is invoking controller methods and redirecting/re-rendering of same or different view is happening.

So I didn't found any standard solution for this problem yet. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with help of javascript,

```
@RequestMapping( value ="/accessDeniedHandler")
public String accessDeniedModal()
{
//Do something here and return modal

return "accessDeniedModal";
}
```

and jsp like this,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function loadModalWindow() {
         // open your window here
         $('<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h3 id="myModalLabel">Access Denied</h3>
  </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p> <Your message> <p>
   </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
</div>
 </div>').modal('show'); 
      }
   </script>
   </head>

    <body onload="loadModalWindow()">

    </body>
 </html>
```

and voila youre modal will open on top of html.